# Why doesn't Spring find the file?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-mvc, mockmvc

I am trying to unit test my fileUpload, after manually testing it with postman, and it working fine. [Postman Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJTWD.png)

```
@Test
public void uploadCompany() throws Exception {

    File companyFile = new File(baseDir + "company.json");

    MockMultipartFile file = new MockMultipartFile("company", "company.json", String.valueOf(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA), Files.readAllBytes(companyFile.toPath()));
    MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(multipart("/fileUpload/").file(file))
            .andReturn();

}
```

And the method called:

```
   private  Object createObject(MultipartFile file){
    JSONObject jsonObject = createJsonObjectFromFile(file);
    Object returnObject;

    Type type = getType(jsonObject);

    returnObject  = switch (type) {
        case NOTSET -> null;
        case TREND -> createTrend(jsonObject);
        case COMPANY -> createCompany(jsonObject);
        case TECHNOLOGY -> createTechnology(jsonObject);
        case PROJECT -> createProject(jsonObject);
    };

    return returnObject;
}
```

When executed this is shown in the console:

> 2022-07-04 17:44:08.078 DEBUG 88988 --- [    Test worker] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to de.fraunhofer.DigiTales2Go.file.FileController#fileUpload(MultipartFile)
> 2022-07-04 17:44:08.090 DEBUG 88988 --- [    Test worker] o.s.web.method.HandlerMethod             : Could not resolve parameter [0] in public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.Object> de.fraunhofer.DigiTales2Go.file.FileController.fileUpload(org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile): Required request part 'File' is not present
> 2022-07-04 17:44:08.092  WARN 88988 --- [    Test worker] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException: Required request part 'File' is not present]

The multipartFile can't be resolved, why?

Answer (score 0):

In the Test, i named the mockFile "company

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).